# How to cut down API requests in AngularJS app

Tags: angularjs, api, request, limit, ngresource

My problem is I'm making too many API requests, which I want to cut down if possible. Below I'll describe the situation:

---

I have three pages, all linked using `ngRoute`. Like this:

```
Page A: Teams (list of teams)
  URL: "/teams"
Page B: Team Details (list of players)
  URL: "/teams/team-details"
Page C: Player Details (list of player stats)
  URL: "/teams/team-details/player-details"
```

Page A is populated by pulling an array of the teams from an API very easily using a simple `$resource.query()` request, and using ng-repeat to iterate through them.

Page B is populated by calling an html template and populating specific fields with values from a **separate API request** to the `/team-details` endpoint, taking the `team_id` value from the clicked element on Page A.

Page C (as with page B) takes a `player_id` from the clicked player on Page B and calls the `/player-details` endpoint using that value. This is **yet another separate request**.

---

This all works fine, but as you can imagine, a single user could quite easily rack up in excess of 100 API requests within an hour.

I have a request limit of **1000/hour**, so if a mere 10 users are online at the same time, it could easily exceed my limit and shut down my API.

If I could access the API as one single master endpoint that outputted all data and subdata in one set, then that would solve my problem, but since I need to request separate endpoints I can't see how to do this.

Is there a better way to approach this? Or are these excessive API requests the only way?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see, Your model looks suitable for the application and meets how an API-driven application should work...

***However***, One potential cut-down you could make is to cache some of the results locally. i.e. store a local version of some of the data that is unlikely to change within a session. For example, If the number of teams is unlikely to change, then store the results of 1 API request locally and use that instead of recalling data from your API.

Following on from this route, you could choose to only update certain data after a certain time period. So, if a user has looked at some `team-details` then refuse to update this data for the next 10-20minutes. However, this does again depend how time-sensitive your data is.

Comment: Thanks. Each endpoint is time-sensitive to a different degree. For example, the `/teams` endpoint could probably be refreshed every hour. `/team-details` and `/player-details` would need to be more frequent. How would you prevent repeat API requests within a certain time period, as you suggest?

Comment: Its quite difficult to get this 100% locked down from the client side. but my approach would be after a successful request (and cache) the store a timestamp locally. I assume your using a `httpInjector` for your `http` calls to your API so that is the place I would check for your timestamp. If the timestamp is < what you want, don't call the API and re-direct to get data from a local cache

Comment: Or when saving data locally (caching) add a timestamp to the data. Then ALWAYS request from cache first. if the data is empty OR the timestamp is too old THEN call API for a refresh. Hope that helps!

Comment: That makes sense - not entirely sure how to implement it, but it's put me on the right path, thanks!